# Firestore rules authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

If my firestore looks like this:

/domain path (eg. xyz.com)/users and other data/ecc

which rule can I set to allow user to access only the domain path they are in? Something like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} { <-- what here
      allow read, write: if request.auth <-- what here ;
    }
  }
}
```

edit: actual firestore screenshot
[image: firestore]

Comment: It's not very clear what your Firestore data looks like and what the specific requirement is.  What does "only the domain path they are in" mean?  It might help to provide a screenshot instead, or provide a more specific path to a document, or code that accesses the document that should be controlled by the rule.

Comment: @DougStevenson please check edit

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have user's domain as collection name so you can use a wildcard as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /{colName}/{docId} {
      allow read, write: if colName == request.auth.token.email.split("@")[1];  
    } 
  }
}
```

This rule will check if the collection name is equal to requesting user's domain in their email.

---

However, this above rule will be applied for all the collections in your database so I'll recommend creating a single collection "users" and storing the domain name as a field as shown below if possible:

```
users -> { userId }
(col)      (doc)
```

```
// document in users collection
{
  email: "user@domain.tld",
  domain: "domain.tld",
  ...otherFields
}
```

You can then easily access the domain name in the security rules from document data.

Comment: it says `Missing or insufficient permissions` when trying to access /ictaio.it/uid from that user

Comment: @TaiTech what is email of the user that you are requesting data with? It must be `xxx@ictaio.it`

Comment: it is, actually I am working with @ictaio.it only

Comment: @TaiTech can you please share your code that is returning that error?

Comment: it is a test in flutter: `await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email!.split('@')[1])
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot value) {
    print(value.docs[0]);
  }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    print(error);
  });` and currentUser is not null